# Schedule Nodemailer email based on info in database

Tags: node.js, express, cron, nodemailer

I am creating an application that stores events and sends reminder emails to people who signed up 1 hour before the event(the time of each event is stored in the database). At first I was thinking about using CronJobs to schedule these emails, but now I am not sure if that will work. Is there any other node module that will allow me to implement the reminder email functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Redis available to backend it, you might look at something like [bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull). 
From the readme:

- Minimal CPU usage due to a polling-free design.
- Robust design based on Redis.
- Delayed jobs.
- Schedule and repeat jobs according to a cron specification.
- Rate limiter for jobs.
- Retries.
- Priority.
- Concurrency.
- Pause/resume—globally or locally.
- Multiple job types per queue.
- Threaded (sandboxed) processing functions.
- Automatic recovery from process crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule). It is using cron-job underneath.

In a quality interval, you can check if there is an upcoming interval, and send the reminder to the appropriate persons.